# Calling a custom class from main

Tags: java

I am trying to print a String from a Node class that I made like so

```
import java.util.*;
public class graph1 {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        ArrayList<Node> web = new ArrayList<Node>();    
        web.add(new Node(0, "a", new int[]{1}));
        ...
        web.add(new Node(14, "o", new int[]{13}));

        for(int i = 0; i < web.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(getTitle.get[i]);
        }
    }
}
public class Node {
    int i;
    String title;
    int[] links;

    Node(int i, String title, int[] links){
        this.i = i;
        this.title = title;
        this.links = links;
    }

    public String getTitle (){
        return title;
    }
    public int[] getlinks (){
        return links;
    }

    public int getIndex (){
        return i;
    }
}
```

I am getting an error saying that getTitle cannot be made into a varible, this makes no sense since it is returning a string.

Comment: You really need to spend sometime on reading Java than simply dumping your issue here. This is I think 4th question within an hour.

Comment: I would suggest you to start with a good Java tutorial, and keep this code aside. You will not get anything hitting in the dark without knowing the basics of `OOP`. So start with classes and objects, and then move gradually towards collections framework.

Comment: I have been working with java for over a year now, I am just really stupid and forget everything all the time.

Comment: @YKQ56. If you are working with Java over a year, then you should certainly change the way you have worked till now.

Comment: How? What do I need to do? All I have been doing is going to class, reading the book and practicing a ton.

Comment: @YKQ56. Which book you've been reading?

Comment: Data Structures outside in with Java.

Comment: What practicing have you been doing? I'd advise a book like Big Java (Horstmann) or Thinking in Java (Eckel). And do the Oracle tutorials. Your questions are so basic - rather than immediately asking for help, study the error messages, use google and really try and understand _why_ your code isn't working

Comment: I just use google and every single search points to some really complex code on this website that answers a different question.

Comment: This isn't a complex question. As I said, go back to basics. Look up arrays and their methods. Then ArrayLists, lists and collections. Understand basic variables. Work through that link I provided in the other question and take it slow. Don't try to move on too quickly. 4 questions in an hour just shows lazyness, not stupidity.

Comment: My class hasn't gotten to array lists yet or collections. I am not lazy, just stupid. I have no resources available to answer my questions except here. I can't find answers to these types of questsions anywhere. I can't find any type of resource that expplains in a clear manner on how to construct an actual java program. Every resource is just 4 lines or code or 1000 lines of complex code. I don't know how to make anything. And of course I am now about to be banned from this site because some idiots decided to dwonvote me.

Comment: @YKQ56 But you cannot waste the time of - how many people do invest time in this basic topic of yours right now - people. You have to get to know those basics yourself. You won't be a serious software developer without doing that.

Comment: I have the basics down, my problem is that I cannot find a good resource to recall these basics except here.

Comment: @YKQ56: You _don't_ have the basics down. That's the problem! You can find these answers online if you take your time. Buy a good Java book and work through it, or use tutorials online. People are downvoting you here because you are posting very simple questions showing little to no personal research.

Comment: Well it is going to get me banned from the website, so I hope that was their intent. It probably already did I just wont' know until I ask a question. I did do research, quite a bit. I spent about an hour reading things that didn't help so I asked here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < web.size(); i++) {
    Node currentNode = web.get(i);
    System.out.println(currentNode.getTitle());
}
```

Comment: Still gives an error. Also why is getTitle called last? I thought it was usually called first.

Comment: I see now I needed parantheses instead of brackets, but I still don't understand why getTitle isn't called first like other commands.

Comment: No I want to print it.

Comment: Because getTitle() is a method that belongs to Node object. when you try to call it by itself, it can't be found anywhere. What Leos told you, verbatim is - from ArrayList of NODE objects, get the Node object at i'th index and call THAT NODE's getTitle() method.

Comment: It isn't a command. It's a method call. And you have to refer to the object first, then comes the method...

Comment: But when I want to add something to a queue it is unqueue.queueName why is this one the other way around?

Comment: In object oriented languages you need to execute an operation on object. So this is why object must be first and then it is followed by operation. E.g. NODE and getTitle().

Comment: blurfus: no, you do not need to - ArrayList<Node> web

Answer (score 2):

getTitle() is a method in a different class, so you must call it through an instance of that class.

```
new Node(...).getTitle();
```

Comment: No. You are calling getTitle.get[i] from a different class. That class has no knowledge of the methods of any other class except those it extends. You can create a new `Node`, call it `myNode` then you can call `myNode.getTitle()`

Comment: His advice is right. In your loop you need web.get(i).getTitle(); instead of getTitle.get[i]

Answer (score 1):

not sure what does not work as you don't provide much to begin with:

the loop seems to be incorrect:

```
for(int i = 0; i < web.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(getTitle.get[i]);

    }
```

should read along the lines of

```
// loop to get each item from ArrayList
for( int i = 0; i < web.size(); i++ ){
  // get a node from array
  Node thisNode = (Node)web.get(i);

  // print its title
  System.out.println( thisNode.getTitle() );

  // print other properties if needed
  System.out.println( thisNode.getIndex() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop should be

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < web.size() ; i++) {
    System.out.println( web.get(i).getTitle() );
```

`web` is an `ArrayList<Node>`.  `web.get(i)` is a `Node`.  And `getTitle()` is applied against this particular `Node`.

However, the previous form is almost in complete disuse.  What you should *really* use is:

```
for(Node webElement : web ) {
    System.out.println( webElement.getTitle() );
```